# Ruby on rails: start_form_tag method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails.  I've been going through a tutorial, but I've gotten stuck.

It has me using `start_form_tag` and `end_form_tag` around an input form.  However, when I access the page, I get `undefined method 'start_form_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2556020>`

In the tutorial, they explain that these two lines are translated into `<form action="/book/create" method="post">` and `</form>`.   As such, I tried putting those instead.  The form out come up, but when I submitted the form, I get this error: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in BookController#create`

So,

1. What do I have to do to get start_form_tag to translate correctly?
2. Is this causing the InvalidAuthenticityToken error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem when I started learning Rails. You have tutorial for old Rails version. `start_form_tag` is no longer used. I think the best place to learn Rails is [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

So, your question now. You can add form like this:

```
<% form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_filed :title %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you're reading is outdated. Forms are now built using `form_for` blocks.

You can find a more up-to-date (and official) guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). You can probably use it to complete the tutorial you're doing now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'book','title' %></p>
<p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
<%= text_field 'book','price'%></p>
<p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
<%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name)%></p>
<p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'book','description'%></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create"%>
<%= link_to 'Back',{:action=>'list'}%>
```